# iOS: Use of other navigation bar for embedded navigation controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In a view controller, I have an embedded NavigationController with disabled navigation bar. I want to use the navigation bar at the beginning for the embedded NC. How can I achieve that?

[image]

Comment: Generally, it's not a good idea to push another NavigationVC inside a NavigationVC as you will issue with navigationbar. Better to simplify your flow.

Comment: The first controller is not a navigation controller, is a normal view controller... which embeds a navigation controller...

Comment: In that case, don't manually add a navigation bar to first Viewcontroller. 
I would suggest you to have UINavigationController as rootViewController and push  other VC inside it. This way you can configure the navigation bar in each subsequent VC.